# How to Display Accordion in Product View Page

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, product-view

Is there a way to show accordion instead of tabbed view for product description for desktop view like its in mobile version of the rwd theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this myself.To change tabs to accordion, edit

**_catalog-product.scss**

```
@include bp(min-width, $bp-medium + 1) {

    .product-collateral {
        @include tabs;
    }
}
```

change this to

```
@include bp(min-width, $bp-medium + 1) {

    .product-collateral {
        @include accordion;
        @include accordionCollapse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above-mentioned method somehow didn't work for me using Magento 1.9.2.0. So I just made some twists in CSS.

1. Remove from line 5360 (@media only screen and (min-width: 771px) {
   .product-collateral .toggle-tabs etc...) to line 5426
2. Remove the closing bracket at line 5527

It means we want to display accordion effect for product collateral for all screens.